# Nav Isn't Vertically Aligned With Parent Div

Tags: html, css, alignment, nav

As illustrated in this screenshot...

[image]

... I have a the red navigation bar which isn't vertically centered with it's parent `div` (the grey bar). I already tried `overflow:hidden`, but this only hides the problem.

#### HTML:

```
  <div class="menu">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#"> <span>Home</span> </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> <span>About</span> </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> <span>Portfolio</span> </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> <span>Contact</span> </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div>
```

#### CSS:

```
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 0%; /*RESET*/
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: #3e3e3e;
    z-index: 9999;

}
nav {
    height:100%;
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#F00;
}
nav ul {
    padding-bottom:20px;
    line-height:0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 50;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#006;
}
```

Comment: Just add `margin:0;` to `nav ul`

Comment: This could be a line-height issue as well. reset your li and ul: `line-height: 1em;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. http://jsfiddle.net/4gf32/2/

```
.menu {
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This will cause the horizontal centering to disappear.

Comment: Right, edited. Adding 'text-align:center' to .menu restores the horizontal align.

Answer (score 1):

Your `nav ul` needs `display: inline-block;` -- Take a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/Wt3HE/

Comment: This will cause the menu items inside the red bar to change vertically. To fix the issue without affecting other things, we need to just set the `ul` to `margin:0;`

Answer (score 0):

I've pasted your code to a jsfiddle and added some:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
} 
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 0%; /*RESET*/
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: #3e3e3e;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-align: center;
}
nav {
    display: inline-block;
    height:100%;
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#F00;
}
nav ul {
    padding-bottom:20px;
    line-height:0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 50;
    height: 50px;
    background-color:#006;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uPPY2/3/

Comment: This will cause the horizontal centering to disappear, unfortunately. All we actually need to do is add `margin:0;` to the `ul`.

Comment: @AndyM is correct, also you can add padding: 0 to the ul. I've updated my jsfiddle